# django ajax return more than one piece of html and mount

Tags: ajax, django

Because of a limitation in bootstrap modals that they need to be outside a postion: fixed, I need to return 2 separate pieces of html in django after an ajax response (a list of items and their modals)

Is there a way in django to return 2 pieces of redendered html?

Currently I have in the ajax view I return a single piece of html with:

`return render(request, 'pages/results.html', context)`

which I mount with:

```
$.ajax({
          url: '/users/some_ajax_view/',
          data: {
            'filters': filters
          },
          success: function (data) {
            $('.ajax-block').html(data)
          }
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solved with using the `render_to_string()` method and then sending multiple pieces of html via a `JsonResponse` to then be mounted on the front end.

eg

in your view:

```
modals_html = render_to_string('components/modals.html', context)
quotes_html = render_to_string('components/list.html', context )
return JsonResponse({'list': list_html,
                         'modals': modals_html})
```

then in the front end mount with:

```
$.ajax({
          url: '/users/some_ajax_view/',
          data: {
            'filters': filters
          },
          success: function (data) {
            $('#list').html(data.list)
            $('#modals').html(data.modals)
          }
        })
```